# File manager to show video bit rate

Tags: nautilus, video, filemanager, exif

Does anyone know a file manager that allows to show videos bit rates when files are viewed as a list? On Nautilus, I have tried [nautilus-columns](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/add-pdf-audio-and-exif-metadata-to.html), and it shows exif for audio files, but not for videos.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider your terminal a file manager ... ffprobe will display media bit rates

```
ffprobe "LarryLessig_2014-480p.mp4"
```

... output

```
ffprobe version N-79477-g3a72760 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.1 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 20160413
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-shared --enable-openssl
  libavutil      55. 22.100 / 55. 22.100
  libavcodec     57. 34.102 / 57. 34.102
  libavformat    57. 34.101 / 57. 34.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 43.100 /  6. 43.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x834ee0] stream 0, timescale not set
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'LarryLessig_2014-480p.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isom
    creation_time   : 2014-03-31 19:32:01
    podcast         : 1
    media_type      : 0
    title           : TED: Larry Lessig (2014)
    artist          : TED
    date            : 2014
    album           : TEDTalks
    comment         : To learn more about this speaker, find other TEDTalks, and subscribe to this Podcast series, visit www.TED.com
                    : Feedback: contact@ted.com
    genre           : Podcast
    category        : Higher Education
  Duration: 00:13:44.19, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1034 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 854x480 [SAR 1280:1281 DAR 16:9], 852 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-03-14 19:16:08
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 76 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-03-31 19:32:01
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Audio Handler
    Stream #0:2: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 3000x3000, 90k tbr, 90k tbn
```

its part of the ffmpeg family of tools

```
apt-get install ffmpeg
```